# I am getting the following errors with my Garry's Mod server

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I've got an addon on my server that basically allows you to create territories. On top of that, I have one which allows you to make permanent properties, which players own even when they aren't online. Additionally, you are able to save the props inside these permanent buildings so that when you next get on, the props are all still there.

It was working fine, but I now seem to be encountering the following error whenever I save the props inside my house and restart the server. Also, a lot of the houses don't seem to work. But, when I unsave the props inside a house and restart, everything is back to normal.

**The error**

```
[ERROR] addons/darkrpmodification-master/lua/darkrp_modules/territory/sh_init.lua:514: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)
1. pairs - [C]:-1
2. LoadProps - addons/darkrpmodification-master/lua/darkrp_modules/territory/sh_init.lua:514
3. tsetUpDoors - addons/darkrpmodification-master/lua/darkrp_modules/territory/sv_init.lua:273
4. unknown - addons/darkrpmodification-master/lua/darkrp_modules/territory/sv_init.lua:290
```

**Code**

```
function BuyableTerritory:LoadProps(steamid, t)
for k, v in pairs(t) do
    local e = ents.Create("prop_physics")
    e:SetPos(v.pos)
    e:SetAngles(v.ang)
    e:SetModel(v.model)
    if v.color then
        e:SetColor(v.color)
    end
    if v.material then
        e:SetMaterial(v.material)
    end 
    e:Spawn()
    e.permaOwner = steamid
    e:GetPhysicsObject():EnableMotion(false)
end
local ply = DarkRP.findPlayer(steamid)
if IsValid(ply) then
    self:SetPropsOwner(ply, ply:SteamID())
end
```

The code starts at line 513, so the second line in is the one having problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error message. It tells you that the input to pairs() is nil instead of the expected table. pairs is a so called iterator. It only works with a Lua table as input.

Your input `t` to `BuyableTerritory:LoadProps(steamid, t)` is not valid.

You either have to change that or check if `t` is a table befor you call `pairs(t)` to prevent the error from happening.

Go to line **273** of **sv_init.lua** to find out whats going on.